Some special series of Bessel functions
I have series of Bessel functions of the form
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{2np}(x)J_{2nq}(y)$
where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. I want to show that when $p, q \to \infty$ then the series converges to zero.
My idea to show this is to show that the series are tails of convergent series, but different pairs of $p$ and $q$ gives different series so I don't know which series these series would be a tail of. Unless one can show that
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} J_{2n}(x)J_{2m}(y)$
converges.

According to WolframAlpha the double series converges to $\frac{1}{4}(1-J_0(x))(1-J_0(y))$. Any idea how I can show this?

It is obvious we may write the double sum as a product:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty J_{2n}(x)J_{2m}(y) =\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n}(x)\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty J_{2m}(y)\right)$$
We may now use the (real part of) the Jacobi-Anger expansion
$$\cos(z\sin\theta)=J_0(z)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(z)\cos(2k\theta)$$
Whereupon taking $\theta=\pi$ we obtain
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(z)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-J_0(z)\right)$$
And hence
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n}(x)\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty J_{2m}(y)\right) =\frac{1}{2}(1-J_0(x))\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1-J_0(y))$$
Therefore, as claimed,
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty J_{2n}(x)J_{2m}(y) =\frac{1}{4}\big(1-J_0(x)-J_0(y)+J_0(x)J_0(y)\big)}$$

The full Jacobi-Anger expansion is proven HERE (rather simply and quickly, I might add). In order to get the formula I used involving $\cos$, one need only take the real part of the full formula.
